# How to adjust the position of specific elements/items/content on a page with CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I am new(ish) to HTML and CSS. I am building a site but it feels I am not getting as much control over it as is possible. Control over positioning and placement of items/elements/objects that is.

[Example Image](http://oi44.tinypic.com/fwhm9s.jpg)

Question: How can I adjust the position of specific elements/items/content on a page with CSS. In this case the 'Horizontal Rule'. How can I move/push the 'Horizontal Rule' up closer to the text above it. The  5 stars and text. And if I wanted to how can I put more space between the title and the image?

For example. In HTML I have a 'Horizontal Rule' separating an image and text above from text below. [See this image here](http://oi44.tinypic.com/fwhm9s.jpg).

The 'Horizontal Rule' in this picture is in a div. The 5 star rating system and it's text is in a div. The picture is in a div and the title (everything above the image) is in a div. Lastly, those 4 divs are in a container div. How can I push the 'Horizontal Rule' up closer to the 5 stars and text with out effecting anything else on the page?

For my code please see my link in the comment below. I am unable to post more than 2 links due to reputation. Thanks.

Your answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post your full HTML or provide a link? This will make it easier to guide you.

Comment: Here is a link to my code. The 'Horizontal Rule' is in the div class 'boxcontent' http://pastebin.com/rj7F2dp3

Comment: In future use JSfiddle for code http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is a good place to start learning HTML/CSS http://freecourses.tutsplus.com/30-days-to-learn-html-and-css/

Comment: I've bookmarked that site. I  looked it over. Looks informative. Lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something such as:

`hr { width: 100%; height: 1px; color: #CCC; margin-top: -2px; }`

Not sure if there is any risk is using negative margins... I'm certainly not a CSS expert.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted too. But since you are not sure if it will have any negative effects I am unsure about it's use or if I should use it. How did that work? Did margin-top: -2px; move the hr to the top of the div? Or did it move it outside the top of the div?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best practice here would be, although I did just discover this article—http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/—which suggests they are perfectly valid to use.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. I have successfully implemented your CSS into my code for both the HR and for the title above the image. Works great for both. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to figure out what you need to change in your CSS to get things closer together or further apart, is to use a developer tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). It allows you to inspect your page elements and not only see what their layout values are, but to edit them as well.

To ensure your `<hr>` tags take up the minimum space, so they are as close to other elements as possible, you can set their margin and padding to 0.

```
hr{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

The next step would be to set the margin and padding of elements above and below your `<hr>` tags.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DUVe5/) that shows the difference by changing the padding/margin of the `<hr>` tags.

It is only the margin that needs to be set, as the padding by default, is already set to zero. [Check here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html) to see the default values for the `<hr>` tag.

Hope this helps